# Get Contact List Images [Avoid OutOfMemory Exception]

Tags: android, bitmap, uri, universal-image-loader

I need to show all the contacts in a listView in my application:

But while showing the Contact Images using the following code :

```
viewholder.imageView.setImageBitmap(MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(activity
                    .getContentResolver(), Uri.parse(currentItem.getContactImage())));
```

that is getting the BitMap in the memory;

GC is been called several time when I scroll my list view and I fear OutOfMemory Exception in this case.

What is the alternative method for this.
I want to avoid getting the images as a BitMap in memory.

Using UniversalImageLoader will help???

Please help!

Thanks in advance.

Comment: do u want to show images from contact list of your phone in listview

Comment: Yes, but with out getting the bitmap in memory

Answer (score 0):

I got this code from stack a long time ago couldn't find the source now but helps to get image from contact list just pass phone number as parameter

```
public Bitmap getFacebookPhoto(String phoneNumber) {
        Uri phoneUri = Uri.withAppendedPath(PhoneLookup.CONTENT_FILTER_URI, Uri.encode(phoneNumber));
        Uri photoUri = null;
        ContentResolver cr = _context.getContentResolver();
        Cursor contact = cr.query(phoneUri,
                new String[] { ContactsContract.Contacts._ID }, null, null, null);

        if (contact.moveToFirst()) {
            long userId = contact.getLong(contact.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts._ID));
            photoUri = ContentUris.withAppendedId(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI, userId);

        }
        else {
            Bitmap defaultPhoto = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(_context.getResources(), android.R.drawable.ic_menu_report_image);
            return defaultPhoto;
        }
        if (photoUri != null) {
            InputStream input = ContactsContract.Contacts.openContactPhotoInputStream(
                    cr, photoUri);
            if (input != null) {
                return BitmapFactory.decodeStream(input);
            }
        } else {
            Bitmap defaultPhoto = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(_context.getResources(), android.R.drawable.ic_menu_report_image);
            return defaultPhoto;
        }
        Bitmap defaultPhoto = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(_context.getResources(), android.R.drawable.ic_menu_report_image);
        return defaultPhoto;
    }
```

Comment: Thanks, but this code gets the bitmap in the memory. And this will lead to OutOfMemory it the Contact list is Huge. I need to show the image using the ContactList Photo uri.